# How many 6digit odd numbers can be written with $0,0,2,2,5,5$

Tags: combinatorics

How many 6digit odd numbers can be written with $0,0,2,2,5,5$

This is how my textbook solve the problem

$(3 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1  \cdot 2) \cdot \frac{1}{2! \cdot 2!} = 18$

But I'm confused, For first digit we can pick four numbers $(2,2,5,5)$ but the textbook puts the three on first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pick four since one of the fives has to be at the end for the number to be odd.

---

Here is my approach: the number you want is the same as the number of five digit integers with digits $0,0,2,2,5$ (since there is already a $5$ at the end.

Now we have that out of the way we can assume all digits are different. Now there are $3$ options for the first digit, $4$ options for the second digit, $3$ options for third digit, $2$ options for the fourth and $1$ option for last.

Therefore the answer would be $3*4*3*2*1$, however we need to divide by $2*2$ since not all digits are the same, we have counted each possibility four times (since permuting the zeroes gives the same number, and so does permuting the twos). Thus the final answer is $\frac{3*4*3*2}{2*2}=3*3*2=18$